# Monotouch "Swipe To Delete" CommitEditingStyle Not Firing

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement "swipe to delete" functionality in a uitableview.  I have followed other tutorials/forums and extended UITableViewSource.  Within that class I have overridden the following methods:

```
public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
   {
       tableItems.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
       tableView.DeleteRows(new [] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
   }
}

public override UITableViewCellEditingStyle EditingStyleForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
}

public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return true;
}
```

I believe these are the only methods I should need. However when I perform a swipe gesture, the CanEditRow and EditingStyleForRow methods are called but CommitEditingStyle is never called.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, when you swipe, `CanEditRow` and `EditingStyleForRow` should be called immediately. Then a "Delete" button should be drawn for you by iOS. After you tap the "Delete" button, `CommitEditingStyle` should be called. Are you seeing the Delete button appear?

Comment: I am NOT seeing the delete button appear. But now I'm nervous that I simply didnt make my view wide enough and it is being covered.  I'll check when I get time later. Thanks for the great info.

Comment: FIXED. That was my problem.  My table was wider than my container so it wasn't showing up.  Facepalm.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah. About that.  Should I be marking my answer as the answer? Or making a new one by me as the answer? Or marking yours up?  I dont know the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question.  It turns out my listview was larger than its container so the delete buttons were simply hidden offscreen. Face palm.

sblom's knowledge about which events get fired when helped me a lot.  Good info.

Comment: Hey, I m trying the same but still my button is not visible, earlier my tableview was out of bound but now i have corrected it., still unable to find the issue

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you *only* have to `override` `CommitEditingStyle` in order to make this work. As long as you're seeing a delete button appear when you swipe one of your rows, you have a very strong indication that all of the tricky parts are working. If you're not seeing a delete button appear when you swipe, we should focus on figuring out why it's AWOL.

Technically, `CanEditRow` is on the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and `EditingStyleForRow` is on `UITableViewDelegate`, so if both of those are indeed being called, we can rule out problems such as your `UITableViewSource` only being assigned to `DataSource` or `Delegate` instead of to the combined `Source` property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am actually NOT seeing the delete button.  Yes, I believe I am setting the Source property correctly but thats a good sanity check.