# commitEditingStyle delete button won't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have an insane issue. I want to implement in my app the "swipe to delete" in my UITableView in Swift.

Something really easy, the swipe works fine, but never showing my red Delete button.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // If a row could not be edited we have to return false for the row index
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    
}
```

I have tested this on 3 new project, when I code theses functions myself, the button never shows, I don't know why!

I have downloaded his code to be sure, and his code works fine, I have the delete button.

My TableView works fine, no bug, no issue, debugger tells me nothing useful. I'm lost! Is this a bug from Xcode?
Here a screen
[My issue](http://anthony-dacruz.com/img/No_Red_button.png)
and what I want :
[Yay](http://anthony-dacruz.com/img/Red_button.png)

Do you guys have any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method? I do not have that method implemented and it works fine. The documentation says: _If this method is not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable._

Comment: Is your delegate set properly and you methods being called?

Comment: Have you implemented the `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` function and set it to return `UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete` for the relevant rows?

Comment: @zisoft : Tried to remove it, but same issue :/

Comment: @Kirsteins My method commitEditingStyle is actually not called nice point here, but still don't know why, delegate fail? but my data is well showed in my tableview however :/

Comment: @pbasdf I tried to implement editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath but still nothing, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the wasted time guys, I had the same issue as here :

[Monotouch "Swipe To Delete" CommitEditingStyle Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660373/monotouch-swipe-to-delete-commiteditingstyle-not-firing)

My table view was larger than the screen scope... So my button was here but I could not see it!

Thanks for your kind help ! *facepalm*